# Internship Interview - Bad Scholastic Record From First School

Tags: interviewing, internship

I started off with a undergraduate degree in Engineering and I did not excel since I was too focused on being cool than being smart at that time. I was a total nerd in high school and I thought I would be able to balance my social life and engineering school: stupid me. After the first year, I was debarred from the Engineering faculty forcing me to transfer schools. I am now pursuing a degree in Information Technology and I have been doing well and I top my class in almost all technical and core subjects.

NOTE: Even though I was debarred from the faculty, there is no stamp or any document stating as I was debarred since I was not kicked out of the university.

I will soon be looking for an internship as it is an undergraduate requirement. These are my following questions:

1. Should I add my first school to my educational background?
2. If I do add it, what would my answer be if they ask why I switched? Should I be honest?(It would be quite a turn off knowing this student was kicked out of engineering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually in a very similar situation.

What I did is the following: I listed the engineering background as incomplete.

When inevitably asked why I didn't finish my Engineering Degree, I turn the whole thing to my advantage:

> I was always a very technically-oriented person, and thought that engineering would be the perfect field for me. However, once I started taking classes such as advanced chemistry, material sciences, and electricity, I discovered that while a lot of these subjects were interesting, and taught very important principles, etc, I had no desire to actually delve into them. I just didn't feel that civil, or electrical engineering were really my calling in life. However, I took a programming class and absolutely loved it. I found this great program offering software development at school X, and transferred there. I've done really well, and here is an unofficial printed version of my transcript to prove it.

People will appreciate you not hiding the fact that you didn't finish your one degree, and also probably respect the fact that you were not afraid to turn around and walk down a path you thought was more appropriate.

Comment: May be a violation of rules and regulations but thank you, sir. This is one of the best pieces of advice I've ever had in my life.

Comment: @jtothebee - thanks for the answer! What do you refer to when you say "May be a violation of rules and regulations"?

Comment: In other SE sites, we refrain from saying "thanks" and "thank you". :) That was addressed to me.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you have a record of successful achievement in your current IT studies the poor performance in engineering shouldn't be a concern. If you're worried about how to address that early part of your studies, you could say something like:

> "Before I started my education, I thought engineering was what I
>   wanted to do. It wasn't and I performed poorly there. I find that I am
>   a much better fit in IT and my academic performance reflects that."

Whatever you say, you have to frame it in the context of you tried this and experienced failure, but didn't let it hold you back from achieving your ccurrent success. Lots of people switch their undergraduate field of study, sometimes drastically.

Comment: @AndreiROM's answer is almost the same as yours and your answer is very appreciated as well. :)

Comment: @jtothebee  Thanks. When I started typing in the answer box, there was no answer. Best of luck to you.